# vbscript - if any file exists then copy and rename

Tags: vbscript

I have a vb script file - main.vbs.  Its contents are:

```
Set fileSystemObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If fileSystemObject.FileExists("D:\a\source.doc") Then
fileSystemObject.CopyFile "D:\b\template.doc", "D:\c\source.doc"
fileSystemObject.MoveFile "D:\a\source.doc" , "D:\d\"
End If
```

What this script does is:  It checks if a file by the name of 'source.doc' exists in folder 'D:\a' .  if it does, then the script,

(i) copies the file 'template.doc' kept in folder 'D:\b'
(ii) renames 'template.doc' to 'source.doc'
(iii) and moves this renamed file to folder 'D:\c'.
(iv) and also moves the file 'source.doc' from 'D:\a' to 'D:\d'

The script is working fine.  But I want that the script should run when the filename 'source' varies (but same extension .doc).

The filename 'template.doc' remains the same.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

This uses the FSO object more like a dir. Do tests on the name to decide if to process it or not. `fso.copyfile` is same as `thing.copy` using a collection and a `For Each` loop.

```
'On Error Resume Next
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dirname = InputBox("Enter Dir name")
ProcessFolder DirName

Sub ProcessFolder(FolderPath)
'    On Error Resume Next
Set fldr = fso.GetFolder(FolderPath)

Set Fls = fldr.files

For Each thing in Fls
     msgbox Thing.Name & " " & Thing.DateLastModified 
Next

'Uncomment below lines to do sub folders
'    Set fldrs = fldr.subfolders
'    For Each thing in fldrs
'        ProcessFolder thing.path
'    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I guess I am not so proficient with vbscript.  Any support I can get please

Comment: any help i can get on this please

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=2764 is VBScript Help. Edit your question with what you've tried.